# Using reference to artifact without multiplying the artifact

Tags: jenkins, plugins, artifact

I've got job that builds jar artifact
In other jobs I want to use this artifact. 
As I understand there is a plugin called "Copy artifact plugin" but it copies file. 
I don't want to have copy of this artifact in every job I created, I want to pass reference to this artifact.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically feasible in situation with multiple slaves. So I believe there is no such functionality in any Jenkins plugin.

You have a choice to even:

1. Force second job to run on master and calculate artifact file path
   from root path configured in Jenkins settings, $JOB_NAME,
   $BUILD_NUMBER, or
2. Upload artifact to an external artifacts repository and later
   reference it, or
3. Save artifacts in a common shared folder accessible from every node.